# SharePoint 2013 Content Search WebPart Query Unable to Exclude People Results

Tags: search, content-search-web-part, search-query

I am using a Content Search WebPart to search for a keyword from 100s of site collections under a web application. I have two content sources:

```
1. http://web.application (All the sites) 
2. sps3://web.application (People results).
```

As the people results are crawled through 2nd content source also I am getting the people results when my search keyword matches the people names/logins.

As I know that the people results are pointing to mysite path. In order to exclude the people results i tried excluding them by Path. Below are the different query text used to exclude the results.

```
{SearchQuery} -Path:"sps3://"
{SearchQuery} -Path:"sps3://*"
{SearchQuery} -Path:"http://mysites"
{SearchQuery} -Path:"http://mysites*"
```

None of them exclude the people results.

But interestingly the query works and returns only people results if NOT is removed from the query.

```
{SearchQuery} Path:"sps3://"
```

**Note**: The default result source "Local SharePoint Results" is used in the Content Search WebPart.

May i know if there is a better approach to exclude the people results. I am okay even if the results are restricted using path.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried putting curly braces around it

```
{{SearchQuery} -Path:"sps3://*"}
```

Or try using the contentclass instead.

```
{{searchTerms} -ContentClass=urn:content-class:SPSPeople}
```